# How to assign function in if condition?

Tags: c++

How do I assign a function in a if-condition in C++?

Say I have the functions f1 and f2 (available and defined in the global environment), and some integer `i`.

I want to define a new function f3, which equals f1 if `i = 1` and f2 otherwise.

How to do this?

Pseudo-code of what I want:

```
if (i == 1)
{
    f3 = f1;
}
else 
{
    f3 = f2;
}

return f3(5);
```

Comment: Did you try it? It should work.

Comment: @ThomasSablik How should it work without a declaration for `f3`?

Comment: You should give us a sufficiently-complete example that we can actually give you an answer that will make the code produce output.

Answer (score 7):

You can declare `f3` as function pointer. You can use an alias or `auto` to make it simpler

```
using F = void(*)(int);
void f1(int) {}

void f2(int) {}

int main() {
    void(*f3)(int);
    F f4 = f1;
    auto f5 = f2;
    int i = 1;
    if (i == 1) {
        f3 = f1;
        f5 = f1;
    } else {
        f3 = f2;
        f4 = f2;
    }
    f3(5);
    f4(10);
    f5(15);
}
```

The name of a function can be used as a pointer: `f1 == &f1`

Answer (score 5):

Use [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) defined in the [functional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) header of STL

Example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int x){
    return x;
}

int bar(int x){
   return x * 2;
}

int main(){
    std::function<int(int)> my_func;
    int condition = 1;
    if (condition == 1){
        my_func = foo;
    }else{
        my_func = bar;
    }
    printf("%d", my_func(5)); // call my_func and print it
}
```

Comment: Yep, a good abstraction over function pointers, and "free" as long as you're not binding/capturing anything.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best option for a polymorphic function is to use a pointer to a function. You can use a pointer like a function, but you can change what it does whenever you need to.
Follow this example

```cpp
void f1(int x1) {
    cout << "f1 "<< x1 << endl;
}

void f2(int x2) {
    cout << "f2 "<< x2 << endl;
}

int main() {

    void (*function_pointer)(int); 

    //Declaration of a function pointer and the type of argument of the function that you 
    // want to point at.

    int x;

    cin >> x;

    if(x == 1) {

        function_pointer = &f1;
    }

    if(x == 2) {

        function_pointer = &f2;
    }

    function_pointer( 2 ); //Usage of a function pointer, as you see, is very similar to a regular 
              // function.

    return 0;
}
```

Greetings.

Comment: I'm not sure that "polymorphic" is the right word here, but function pointers are the appropriate solution.